# How to make a random falling of bitmaps in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I wanted to create something like jetboy asteroids  that I found on android samples but i'ts too complicated to get the right code and to make it work properly.
I don't want on touch simply the asteroids should begin themselves.
Can someone link me some good stuff or give me some examples?

```
 private void doAsteroidCreation() {
    // Log.d(TAG, "asteroid created");

    Asteroid _as = new Asteroid();

    int drawIndex = mRandom.nextInt(4);

    // TODO Remove hard coded value
    _as.mDrawY = mAsteroidMinY + (drawIndex * 63);

    _as.mDrawX = (mCanvasWidth - mAsteroids[0].getWidth());

    _as.mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    mDangerWillRobinson.add(_as);
}
```